# PSR-12 - method chaining, line breaks, and indentation

Tags: php, psr-12

What is the correct indentation for the following code examples according to PSR-12?

```
$object->method1(function () {
    # do things
})
    ->method2(function () {
        # do things
    });
```

and

```
$object->method1(
    $val1,
    $val2,
    ... (long enough to require multiple lines)
)
    ->method2(
        $val1,
        $val2,
        ... (long enough to require multiple lines)
    );
```

As far as I can tell, they're correct... but it looks so wrong, like `method2` is a child of `method1`. From what I've read, the closing parenthesis for `method1` should have the same indentation as the line its opening parenthesis is on (no indentation), and that `method2` should be indented.

I sure hope I'm misreading the guidelines, but the IDE formatting tools seem to agree on this as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think by spec, either one is correct, but for what it's worth, I always do it look this, and I think this is also in accordance with the spec:

```
$object
    ->method1(
        $val1,
        $val2,
    )
    ->method2(
        $val1,
        $val2,
    );
```

https://phptools.online/php-checker/result/a200cfcd-b7b9-42cf-88fd-2949000feb58

Comment: Hmm… What if `ClassName::` used instead of `$object->`?